# Populate 2D arrays using a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, hl7-v2

I'm attempting to parse a pipe delimited line of text from a file - HL7 message segment - to make the segment a property of an HL7 message object.

I think I"m fundamentally not understanding the concept of n-dimensional arrays...

The segment looks like this

> MSH|^~\&||X530^X530^FID|ERIC^NSCC^RSSI|NSCCH|....

*I want to create an array thusly;*

First item in the array = {"0","MSH"}

Next  item in the array = {"1,", "^~\&"}

Next  item in the array = {"2,", null}

Next  item in the array = {"3,", "X530^X530^FID"}

I get error message:

[image: error message]

```
    private string [,] ParseSegment(string ms)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] segmentFields = ms.Split('|');//fields for this segment
        int arrayLength = segmentFields.Length;
        string[,] fieldAndIndex = new string[arrayLength,1];

        foreach (string field in segmentFields)
        {
            fieldAndIndex [i,i] = {{ i,field} };//I'm not sure what to do here!!!!
        }

        return fieldAndIndex;
    }
```

Comment: why do you need a 2d array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each sub array of your 2D array has 2 items (right?), so you should have a `2` instead of a `1` as the length:

```
string[,] fieldAndIndex = new string[arrayLength, 2];
```

Since you want a counter variable `I` in the loop, you should not use a `foreach` loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayLength ; i++) {
    // here you want the first item of the subarray to be i, and the second item to be the corresponding segment
    fieldAndIndex[i, 0] = i.ToString();
    fieldAndIndex[i, 1] = segmentFields[i];
}
```

Also, I don't think a 2D array is suitable here. Storing the index of each element (which is what you seem to be trying to do) is unnecessary, because `fieldAndIndex[x, 0]` will always be the same as `x`!

You might want to use a simple 1D array instead. There are other data structures that might be useful:

- `Dictionary<int, string>`
- `(int, string)[]`
- `string[][]`

Answer (score 2):

To understand the basic array in your case you can consider the array to be a 2D Matrix. Similarly you can consider a 3D array a cube. What you are trying to do is add two item in one place

```
fieldAndIndex [i,i] = {{ i,field} };
```

So during the first iteration the notation [i,i] evaluates to [0,0] which means the first element in the first row. 
The proper way to insert these both can be done as shown by the given answer

```
fieldAndIndex [i,i] = i.ToString();
fieldAndIndex [i,++i] = field.ToString();
```

I hope this resolves your issue it is better to go through some research on multi dimensional arrays. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm) and [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) are some good links to get started on these arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private string [] ParseSegment(string ms) //you do not need 2d array for that
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] segmentFields = ms.Split('|');//fields for this segment
        int arrayLength = segmentFields.Length;
        string[] fieldAndIndex = new string[arrayLength];

        foreach (string field in segmentFields)
        {
            fieldAndIndex [i] = field;
            i++;
        }

        return fieldAndIndex;
    }
```

You do not need 2d array(matrix) to parse that (calling fieldAndIndex[n] will just give it's value - fieldAndIndex[1] == "^~\&""), but if you really need to :

```
    private string [,] ParseSegment(string ms) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] segmentFields = ms.Split('|');//fields for this segment
        int arrayLength = segmentFields.Length;
        string[,] fieldAndIndex = new string[arrayLength,2];

        foreach (string field in segmentFields)
        {
            fieldAndIndex [i][0] = i;
            fieldAndIndex [i][1] = field;
            i++;
        }

        return fieldAndIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While I dont understand why you would want a 2 dimentional array.

`new string[arrayLength,1];` should be `new string[arrayLength,2];`

`[i,i]` expects 1 element, not 2. Also you need to use `[i,0]` and `[i,1]`

```
private string [,] ParseSegment(string ms)
{
    int i = 0;
    string[] segmentFields = ms.Split('|');//fields for this segment
    int arrayLength = segmentFields.Length;
    string[,] fieldAndIndex = new string[arrayLength,2];

    foreach (string field in segmentFields)
    {
        fieldAndIndex [i,0] =  i.ToString();
        fieldAndIndex [i,1] =  field;
        i++;
    }

    return fieldAndIndex;
}
```